# The provider provider.google does not support resource type "google_cloudfunctions2_function"

Tags: terraform, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I have an issue while i try to deploy a google function gen2.
Here is my configuration environment

```
**gcloud -v**
Google Cloud SDK 402.0.0
alpha 2022.09.12
beta 2022.09.12
bq 2.0.75
core 2022.09.12
gsutil 5.13
pubsub-emulator 0.7.0

**terraform -v**
Terraform v0.14.11

**terraform init**
Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/archive from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/google from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/google-beta from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/null from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/random from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/time from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/template from the dependency lock file
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/archive v2.2.0
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/google v3.90.1
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/google-beta v3.90.1
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/null v3.1.1
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/random v3.4.3
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/time v0.8.0
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/template v2.2.0

**terraform plan**
Error: Invalid resource type

  on modules/shared/functions/main.tf line 206, in resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "mergeopenapi_trigger_function":
 206: resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "mergeopenapi_trigger_function" {

*The provider provider.google does not support resource type
"google_cloudfunctions2_function".*
```

Could someone can help me fix it ?

Thanks a lot

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to upgrade your hashicorp/google version.

You can see [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs) in the latest version of the provider (4.4.0 as of this writing) that Cloud Functions 2nd gen exists.

If you change the docs URL from 4.4.0 to 3.90.1, that 2nd gen doesn't exist.

According to the changelog, that data source wasn't added until yesterday:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

EDIT: oops! got my date wrong on the changelog. looks like cloudfunction2 was promoted to GA in 4.34.0.